# $PA = LU$ Decomposition Confusion

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

In general I know how to do PA = LU. Basically we do A = LU decomposition first, and then do row swap and change the value of P.

But I've got a weird problem from my prof.

$
   A =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   0 & 0 & 1 & -3 & 2 \\
   2 & -1 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
   4 & -2 & 9 & 1 & 4 \\
   2 & -1 & 5 & -1 & 5 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

Here'a my steps to do the decomposition:

**Remove the last column because PA = LU decomposition can only perform on n by n matrix.**

row 4 <-- row 2 - row 4

$
   U =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   0 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
   2 & -1 & 4 & 2 \\
   4 & -2 & 9 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & -1 & 3 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

$
   L =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   1 &  &  &  \\
    & 1 &  &  \\
    &  & 1 &  \\
    1 & 1 &  & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

row 4 <-- row 1 + row 4

$
   U =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   0 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
   2 & -1 & 4 & 2 \\
   4 & -2 & 9 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

$
   L =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   1 &  &  &  \\
    & 1 &  &  \\
    &  & 1 &  \\
    1 & 1& -1  & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

row 3 <-- (-2) * row 2 + row 3

$
   U =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   0 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
   2 & -1 & 4 & 2 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

$
   L =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   1 &  &  &  \\
    & 1 &  &  \\
   2 & 2 & 1 &  \\
    1 & 1& -1  & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

row 3 <--  row 1 - row 3

$
   U =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   0 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
   2 & -1 & 4 & 2 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

$
   L =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   1 &  &  &  \\
   0 & 1 &  &  \\
    2 & 2 & 1 &  \\
    1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

However

L * U = $\left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
   1 &  &  &  \\
   0 & 1 &  &  \\
    2 & 2 & 1 &  \\
    1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

- $\left[ {\begin{array}{cccc}
     0 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
     2 & -1 & 4 & 2 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{array} } \right]$

=

$\left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   0 & 0 & 1 & -3 \\
   2 & -1 & 4 & 2 \\
   4 & -2 & 10 & -2 \\
   2 & -1 & 5 & -3 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

The third and fourth rows are different from the original A, but I am not sure which steps are wrong..

Comment: In general, it may be necessary to do row swaps as you go along rather than at the very end.

Comment: @BrianBorchers but why would it make a difference when I do it along the way vs. do it at the end? I remembered I tried to do the row swaps along the way but it still doesn't work... :(

Comment: If your pivot element is 0, then you can't use that row to eliminate entries below the 0.